# Plotting GPS coordinates in ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap

I have one problem. When I plot my coordinates using ggmap it does not connect segments according to date column. I end up having a weird map. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks for your help in advance.

this is what did.

```
p=ggmap(mapImageData)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, group=DataID, color=factor(DataID)), 
            size = 4,
            pch= 20,
            data=koeco)
p + geom_line(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, group=DataID, color=factor(DataID)),
            size = 1,
            data=koeco) +
  theme_bw() +
  annotate("text", x=110.3539, y=48.8, label = "Start", 
                       colour = I("red"), size = 5) +
  annotate("text", x=116.2648, y=28.5, label = "End",
           colour = I("red"), size = 5) +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", colour = "Routes")
```

[image: crane movement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help for `geom_line` says:

```
Description:

     Connect observations, ordered by x value.
```

The help for `geom_path` says:

```
Description:

     Connect observations in original order
```

So I'm guessing you should use `geom_path`. Its a guess because you haven't given us some data to try this on.

By "original order" it means the order in the data frame. If your data isn't in date-sorted order then it will still jump around, but I'm guessing (also) that your data frame is sorted by date (these things usually are).

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. My data was date-sorted. Thanks a lot.